# Get tweets with html, like in Twitter widget

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-search

I am trying to get tweets from Twitter with text body, like in Twitter widget, using search API v1.1. What is the problem. This is my code:

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $twitter_access_token['oauth_token'], $twitter_access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
$tweets = $connection->get('search/tweets', ['count' => 30, 'result_type' => 'mixed', 'q' => $hashtags]);
return $tweets;
```

Each tweet has property "text", which contains something like this: 
[tweet object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRxGa.jpg)

Here also can be images, quotes, etc. All of this is just text. Whithout html tags. But if I use widget, it returns something like this:
[tweet structure in widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE6M4.jpg)

As you can see, quotes, hashtags, images and other stuff are wrapped in html tags and are displayed not like just text.

How can I get tweets with such text (with html tags), using search API v1.1? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would be surprised if Twitter provided tweet data already formatted in this way. APIs are generally used to get _data_. Then you can format it however you want.

Comment: @Chris But, I think, there should be the solution, how I can achieve my goal. I am sure, I am not the only one, who want to show tweets in nice way, not just boring text.

Comment: Sergey, nothing is preventing you from showing tweets "in a nice way". But the API doesn't return tweet data already formatted. It gives you the _raw data_ so you can format it yourself.

Comment: I've tried to write my own parser (with own bugs), but then I found this library, which helped me a lot: [TwitterTextFormatter](http://blog.netgloo.com/2015/08/16/php-getting-latest-tweets-and-displaying-them-in-html/)